# how to get id of every item in checkboxlists databound event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, databound

I have a `CheckBoxList` and I need to get the `id` of each item in it on its `DataBound` event and I don't know how to get it, please help me.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstArea"
                  RepeatColumns="6" 
                  RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
                  runat="server"
                  ondatabound="chklstArea_DataBound">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

here is code behind code:

```
 protected void drpLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (drpLocation.SelectedItem.Value != "")
    {
        lbtnSelectArea.Visible = true;
        objAreaNew = new ClsAreaNew();
        ClsAreaNewProp objAreaNewProp = new ClsAreaNewProp();
        objAreaNewProp.LocationId = Convert.ToInt64(drpLocation.SelectedItem.Value);
        DataTable dtAreaByLocId = objAreaNew.GetAllAreaListByLocID(objAreaNewProp);
        if (dtAreaByLocId.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            divAreaListingHeader.Visible = true;
            chklstArea.DataSource = dtAreaByLocId;
            chklstArea.DataTextField = "AreaName";
            chklstArea.DataValueField = "areaid";
            chklstArea.DataBind();
            lblStatusMessage.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            divAreaListingHeader.Visible = false;
            dtAreaByLocId = null;
            chklstArea.DataSource = dtAreaByLocId;
            chklstArea.DataTextField = "AreaName";
            chklstArea.DataValueField = "areaid";
            chklstArea.DataBind();
            lblStatusMessage.Text = "This Location does not have any area.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lbtnSelectArea.Visible = false;
        divAreaListingHeader.Visible = false;

        chklstArea.DataSource = null;
        chklstArea.DataTextField = "AreaName";
        chklstArea.DataValueField = "areaid";
        chklstArea.DataBind();
        lblStatusMessage.Text = "Please select location.";
    }
}
```

Actually what i need to do is:
i need to bind another checkbox list on the bases of id of items binding in this checkbox list.
like here i am binding areas. now i want to bind another checkbox list of rooms the id of area id i want to use to get rooms of that particular area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement and according to my understand you need to use repeater or any other databound control containing the checkbox list. as below:

**HTML Code is:**

```
<div class="outerlin" id="divAreaListingHeader" runat="server" style="margin-top: 15px;
                            width: 99%;">
                            <div class="maintitle">
                                Areas</div>
                            <br />
                            <span style="float: left; padding-left: 7px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" />Select All<br />
                            </span>
                            <div id="divAreaListingByLocation">
                                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstArea" RepeatColumns="6" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server">
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div class="outerlin" id="divRoomListingHeader" style="margin-top: 15px; width: 99%;">
                            <asp:Repeater ID="repRooms" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repRooms_ItemDataBound">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="maintitle">
                                        Rooms</div>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAreaName" ForeColor="Green" BackColor="Red" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <span style="float: left; padding-left: 7px;">
                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Checkbox1" Text="Select All" />
                                        <%--<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="Checkbox1" />Select All--%><br />
                                    </span>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <div id="divRoomListingByLocation">
                                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkRoomList" RepeatColumns="6" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server">
                                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
```

**And code behind is:**

```
protected void repRooms_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ClsRoomNew objRoom = new ClsRoomNew();
    CheckBoxList chkRoomList = (CheckBoxList)e.Item.FindControl("chkRoomList");
    CheckBox Checkbox1 = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("Checkbox1");
    Label lblAreaName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblAreaName");

    if (chkRoomList != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = objRoom.RoomListingByAreaId(Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Areaid")));
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblAreaName.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Areaname").ToString();
            chkRoomList.DataSource = dt;
            chkRoomList.DataTextField = "RoomName";
            chkRoomList.DataValueField = "RoomId";
            chkRoomList.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Checkbox1.Visible = false;
            chkRoomList.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

try this hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

chklstArea.ClientID will give you the client id of the "CheckBoxList" Control. 
And for getting clientIds of individual checkboxes you can use following code.

```
int index = 0;
string checkBoxIDs = ""; //Comma Seperated IDs
foreach (ListItem listItem in chklstArea.Items)
{
  checkBoxIDs = chklstArea.ClientID + "_" + index + ",";
  index++;
}
```